# How does UnsafeCell inform rustc to opt out of alias based optimizations?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I was reading the [rust std doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) and came across this line:

> `UnsafeCell<T>` opts-out of the immutability guarantee for `&T`: a shared reference `&UnsafeCell<T>` may point to data that is being mutated. This is called "interior mutability".

Does this mean one can create thier own version of `UnsafeCell<T>` and opt out of alias based optimizations done on `&T` ? How does `UnsafeCell<T>` inform rustc that it should not do alias based optimizations ? Is there some attribute for it or is the rustc compiler written to recognize `UnsafeCell<T>` with a hard coded built in rule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read all of this up on your own, the source code is free to browse after all. `UnsafeCell` behaves how it does because it's declared as [implementing the language item `unsafe_cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cell.rs.html#1983-1988):

> ```
> #[lang = "unsafe_cell"]
> #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
> #[repr(transparent)]
> pub struct UnsafeCell<T: ?Sized> {
>     value: T,
> }
> ```

If you don't include `core` you can implement your own version, but only on nightly since it requires 2 features to be enabled:

```rust
#![feature(no_core, lang_items)]
#![no_core]
#[lang = "unsafe_cell"]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct MyUnsafeCell<T: ?Sized> {
    v: T
}
```

Comment: where can one get the list of all lang_items ? is it documented somewhere ? and what about the list of all arrtibutes ?

Comment: Yes, there is a [List of all language items in the Unstable Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/lang-items.html#list-of-all-language-items)

Comment: thanks a ton. on the same not what about the list of all annotations/attributes that one can use ?

Comment: Note that _you're not supposed to use `lang_items`, and it's highly unstable_. There's even a lint for that: `internal_features`.

Comment: @AkashR there is no list of all such annotations one can use, because anyone can define them, through macros. These annotations are absolutely not intended to be used by Rust programmers and, as such, never appear in user documentation.